# Able to override the root permission of a readonly file with a non-sudo user

Tags: linux, bash, docker, vim

I was performing some experiments in [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) and found a strange behaviour.

I was able to override the ownership of a file created with the root
user inside the Docker with another user without root permissions.

Below are the steps to reproduce it:

```
$> docker run -dit ubuntu:16.04 bash
$> docker exec -it cont_id bash
$> apt update && apt install -y vim
$> useradd cp -m
$> vim /home/cp/hello.txt
  #  Write some text and save it

$> su cp 
$> cd ~/ && ls -latr;
  #  Will list hello.txt with user and group as root

$> vim hello.txt
  #  Write some text and try saving it normally which will fail.
  #  Try saving it with `:wq!`
```

Voila, it is saved and the user and group to which the file belongs also change to the new user.

I have done a terminal recording for this and the same is posted [here](https://asciinema.org/a/HhS1zIShEMs6lD0JPiyRKTGJl).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not related to docker, but just normal behavior in `vim`. As the file is under user directory `/home/cp`, hence `cp` user will have all permissions. What `wq!` command does is to delete the the old one and put new content into `/home/cp/hello.txt`.

You can quickly test it by creating one more file in the folder that `cp` has no full permission.

Comment: Indeed!. I tried in the `/opt` folder, and couldn't see that coming. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You were able to do it because you have all permission to directory /cp.
For doing it there are only two options:

1. If you're the owner of the file. Then vim changes permission to write(w)and rewrite the file. and after saving it, restores the old permissions of the file.
2. If you are not the owner of the file, but if you have write permissions in the current directory, Vim will delete the original file and write the document to a new file with the same name. The new file will then be assigned the same permissions as the original file, but will be owned by you.

These are only two conditions in which read-only file can be overridden.